# Por que me duplica la misma ventana?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un codigo en c# en el cual abre una ventana al darle click al boton la cual es la segunda ventana y  se ingresan los datos, una vez ingresado los datos se le da click y se cierra la segunda ventana   pero se duplica la primera ventana uno con los datos y otra vacía,alguien sabe por que sucede esto ya intente cerrar la ventana principal los combobox y los texbox tiene acceso publico no se si tenga algo que ver eso que se duplique el mismo formulario

Ventana 1 la cual se duplica dos veces:

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btn_SC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FColores fColores = new FColores();
        fColores.ShowDialog();



    }
}
```

Ventana 2

```
public partial class FColores : Form
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    public FColores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string a;
    private double b;

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;

            case 1:
                a = "1";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                break;

            case 2:
                a = "2";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;

            case 3:
                a = "3";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;

            case 4:
                a = "4";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;

            case 5:
                a = "5";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;

            case 6:
                a = "6";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;

            case 7:
                a = "7";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                break;

            case 8:
                a = "8";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                break;

            case 9:
                a = "9";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;

        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                a += "0";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Black;

                break;

            case 1:
                a += "1";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                break;

            case 2:
                a += "2";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;

            case 3:
                a += "3";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;

            case 4:
                a += "4";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;

            case 5:
                a += "5";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;

            case 6:
                a += "6";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;

            case 7:
                a += "7";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                break;

            case 8:
                a += "8";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                break;

            case 9:
                a += "9";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;

        }
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox3.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Black;

                break;

            case 1:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0";
                a += "0";
                break;

            case 2:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "00";
                a += "00";
                break;

            case 3:
                form.button3.BackColor= Color.Orange;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "000";
                a += "000";
                break;


            case 4:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0000";
                a += "0000";
                break;

            case 5:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "00000";
                a += "00000";
                break;

            case 6:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "000000";
                a += "000000";
                break;

            case 7:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0000000";
                a += "0000000";
                break;

            case 8:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "" + 0.1;
                b = double.Parse(a) * 0.1;
                a = b.ToString();
                break;

            case 9:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.White;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "" + 0.01;
                b = double.Parse(a) * 0.01;
                a = b.ToString();
                break;

        }
    }



    private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox4.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-2%";

                break;

            case 1:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Gold;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-5%";

                break;

            case 2:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Silver;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-10%";
                break;



        }
    }
     private void btn_Calcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        form.Show();
        this.Close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Coloqué una respuesta argumentada y bien explicativa, por que es evidente que has estado creando dos instancias de ´Form1´ y por eso se duplica la primera ventana, con el código que has escrito, no podía ser de otra forma. Espero que pruebes lo que te coloque en la respuesta debe resultarte, pues lo he usado en muchas ocasiones, espero además que puntees mi respuesta, seria un estimulo para mi, pues soy usuario nuevo y además desarrollador autodidacta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene un error de concepto. Tienes una Ventana 1 `Form1` que crea una Ventana 2 llamada `FColores`, pero en tu código, dentro de `FColores` lo primero que haces es crear una nueva instancia de `Form1` y digo una nueva instancia, por que al hacer `Form1 form = new Form1();`creaste una nueva Ventana 1 ó `Form1` como se llama realmente en tu código

```
public partial class FColores : Form
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    public FColores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string a;
    private double b;
```

y a ese nuevo `Form1` es al que le asignas valores y finalmente lo muestras.

```
private void btn_Calcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Aquí muestras un nuevo Form 1, no es la Ventana 1, es una nueva ventana que creaste
        form.Show();
        this.Close();

    }
```

Si lo que quieres es cambiar valores de la Ventana 1, desde la Ventana 2, aunque no entiendo para que puede servir eso, tendrás que hacer referencia a la Ventana 1, desde el código de la Ventana 2, fijate hacer referencia a la Ventana 1, no crear una nueva instancia de `Form1` en la Ventana 2.
Este seria tu código de la Ventana 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = false;
        button3.Enabled = false;
        button4.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void btn_SC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FColores fColores = new FColores();
        //Colocas a la propiedad Parent el Form1.
        fColores.Parent = this; 
        fColores.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Y el código de tu Ventana 2, seria:

```
public partial class FColores : Form
{
    //Declarar la variable para almacenas la referencia a Form1
    Form1 form;
    public FColores()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Recuperar la propiedad Parent y asignarla a la variable form
        form = this.Parent as System.Windows.Forms;
    }
    private string a;
    private double b;

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
                break;
            case 1:
                a = "1";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                break;
            case 2:
                a = "2";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
             case 3:
                a = "3";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;
            case 4:
                a = "4";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
             case 5:
                a = "5";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;
            case 6:
                a = "6";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;
            case 7:
                a = "7";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                break;
             case 8:
                a = "8";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                break;
            case 9:
                a = "9";
                form.button1.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;

        }
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox2.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                a += "0";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Black;

                break;

            case 1:
                a += "1";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                break;

            case 2:
                a += "2";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;

            case 3:
                a += "3";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                break;

            case 4:
                a += "4";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;

            case 5:
                a += "5";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                break;

            case 6:
                a += "6";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                break;

            case 7:
                a += "7";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                break;

            case 8:
                a += "8";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                break;

            case 9:
                a += "9";
                form.button2.BackColor = Color.White;
                break;

        }
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox3.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Black;

                break;

            case 1:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0";
                a += "0";
                break;

            case 2:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Red;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "00";
                a += "00";
                break;

            case 3:
                form.button3.BackColor= Color.Orange;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "000";
                a += "000";
                break;


            case 4:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0000";
                a += "0000";
                break;

            case 5:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Green;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "00000";
                a += "00000";
                break;

            case 6:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Blue;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "000000";
                a += "000000";
                break;

            case 7:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Violet;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "0000000";
                a += "0000000";
                break;

            case 8:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "" + 0.1;
                b = double.Parse(a) * 0.1;
                a = b.ToString();
                break;

            case 9:
                form.button3.BackColor = Color.White;
                form.txt_Multi.Text = "" + 0.01;
                b = double.Parse(a) * 0.01;
                a = b.ToString();
                break;

        }
    }



    private void comboBox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (comboBox4.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Red;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-2%";

                break;

            case 1:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Gold;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-5%";

                break;

            case 2:
                form.button4.BackColor = Color.Silver;
                form.txt_Tolerancia.Text = "+-10%";
                break;
        }
    }
     private void btn_Calcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Eliminar esta linea pues el Form1 ya no hay mostrarlo
        //form.Show(); 
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: form = this.Parent as System.Windows.Forms aparece un error llamado 'System.Windows.Forms es espacio de nombres pero se usa como tipo'

Comment: @kevinhernandez Tienes razón la sentencia es ´System.Windows.Forms.Form´ quedaría como sigue ´form = this.Parent as System.Windows.Forms.Form´ pruebalo y funcionará.

Comment: @kevinhernandez Disculpa por el error en mi respuesta, pero subsanando ese error como te dije en el comentario anterior ´form = this.Parent as System.Windows.Forms.Form´, puedo asegurar que funcionará,  te pido si te resulta que puntees mi respuesta, seria un estimulo para mi, pues soy usuario nuevo y además desarrollador autodidacta.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que tu error esta ahi

```
private void btn_Calcular_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   // form.Show(); Comenta esta linea. Estas volviendo a abrir el mismo formulario.
    this.Close();

}
```